# In Selenium IDE how can you select an option by index in a dropdown menu?

Tags: select, selenium

The problem is the option labels change and so I cant grab by label. I need to grab by say option[0]

any idea?

I'm using Selenium IDE (Firefox), this is the piece im asking about:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>dateRangeString</td>
    <td>index=1</td>
</tr>
```

the last TD there is the VALUE field in the IDE,

I already am targeting the select element, but i need to simulate the user selecting the first option. The only way I see to do this is by using LABEL="string" in the VALUE part of the IDE, but string is dynamic so thats not going to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky, but the "type" command helped me here:

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=numStuff</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

The corresponding html looks like this (except the @id and @name attributes)

```
<select id="numStuff" name="numStuff">
                        <option selected= value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

I'm wondering if it works for option values longer than 1 keystroke. At least, it's good for the time being.

Answer (score 12):

you can select it by using the XPath `//select/option[index]`.

Remember that XPath is a 1 based index by standard.

**Edit After Question was updated**

You can use a number of different ways to select an option from within a select. Below has been copied from the Selenium IDE on how to create option locators. To select the first item it would be `index=0`

> select(selectLocator, optionLocator)
>       Arguments:
>
> ```
>     * selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
>     * optionLocator - an option locator (a label by default)
>
> Select an option from a drop-down using an option locator.
>
> Option locators provide different ways of specifying options of an HTML
> ```
>
> Select element (e.g. for selecting a
>   specific option, or for asserting that
>   the selected option satisfies a
>   specification). There are several
>   forms of Select Option Locator.

```
    * label=labelPattern: matches options based on their labels, i.e. the visible text. (This is the default.)
          o label=regexp:^[Oo]ther
    * value=valuePattern: matches options based on their values.
          o value=other
    * id=id: matches options based on their ids.
          o id=option1
    * index=index: matches an option based on its index (offset from zero).
          o index=2
```

> ```
> If no option locator prefix is provided, the default behaviour is to
> ```
>
> match on label.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what my needs are. I already am targeting the select element, but i need to simulate the user selecting the first option. The only way I see to do this is by using LABEL="label string" in the VALUE part of the IDE

Comment: Yeah I figured out how to use index=index before you posted your update =] I had that initially but it didnt seem to work. I had to do some wait command. But thanks for the full info. Do you know where you can find documentation for this some place?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using label="", try using index="1" (to select the first element). Selenium offers label="", id="", value="", and index="" for this sort of cases. For more details, see:

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
select | Locator | index=1 |
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, i solved this by using:
selenium.Select("id=yourID", "index="+i.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

In selenium IDE I used:

> Command:  select 
>   Target:  XPath target ending in select (not option). XPath can be obtained with FireBug and FirePath. 
>   Value:  E.G. "Texas"
>   or whatever value pattern you require