# Select option with key "space"(&nbsp;) in the Selenium IDE

Tags: html, select, selenium, selenium-ide

I have select and two option inside with mark "space" (Look Jsfiddle, please). I can't to select option in my select use my test in Selenium IDE. How can I do it?

#### *It's JSFiddle:*

http://jsfiddle.net/fgh9szk3/1/

#### This my select:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">USD &nbsp;</option>
    <option value="3">EUR &nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

#### This my test in Selenium IDE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://jsfiddle.net/fgh9szk3/1/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>css=#select</td>
    <td>USD</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By index? by value? ide should andele this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select it [by `label`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942852/771848) (meaning *visible text*), providing a regular expression:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>css=#select</td>
    <td>label=regexp:^USD</td>
</tr>
```

where `^` matches the beginning of a string.

Comment: It's works. I don't know that can to use regexp. Thanks!